# How to concat two columns and add a brackets around the new column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, concatenation

I have a dataframe like below

```
id | column A | Column B | Column C
123| apple    | Vitamins | Minerals
```

I want to concatenate columns B and C and add brackets around the text like [B,C]. i.e [Vitamins,Minerals]
Please help.

Comment: Please don't use image link in the question. It makes it difficult for answerer to copy data and for others to view the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `concat`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('columnD', F.expr("concat('[', columnB, ',', columnC, ']')"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured I will post an entire working code to make it easier for you to understand. The ley is to use the `concat` keyword to achieve the desired result.

**Code:**

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

my_list = [
  {"id ":'123',"column A":'apple',"column B":'Vitamins',"column C":'Minerals'}
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in my_list)
df.show()
df = df.withColumn('joined_column', fn.concat(fn.lit('['),df['column B'],fn.lit(','), df['column C'],fn.lit(']')))
df.show()
```

**Run Results:**

```
+--------+--------+--------+---+
|column A|column B|column C|id |
+--------+--------+--------+---+
|   apple|Vitamins|Minerals|123|
+--------+--------+--------+---+

+--------+--------+--------+---+-------------------+
|column A|column B|column C|id |      joined_column|
+--------+--------+--------+---+-------------------+
|   apple|Vitamins|Minerals|123|[Vitamins,Minerals]|
+--------+--------+--------+---+-------------------+
```

Comment: Could you please remove the image and the results as text?

Comment: @koiralo Sure, but out of curiosity is there any such guideline? I understand how that would affect the code, but the results too?

Comment: Nothing specific in guideline for results, but if someone want to copy the data and have a quick compare or test, in that case it would be much more easier.